# Generate string in different languages in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, random

I can generate random string just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript).

But are there some tools to generate same string according to user language? So you can just pass language code and get a string?

Comment: You have to first generate a "possible" list of characters for each language somehow

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you mean? In which language do you want the code?

Comment: @FlowX
code in javascript.
string languages - English, Ukrainian, Polish, Spanish ...

Comment: What do you mean by `generate same string according to user language`?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called "internationalization" or i18n.

If you google "javascript internationalization" you'll find several projects that could help, including:

http://i18next.com/

http://formatjs.io/

https://slexaxton.github.io/Jed/

I've used Jed before and it worked well for me.

Comment: whatever the OP really asks or want, I believe this is the only acceptable answer that can be provided ☺

Comment: Hmm actually upon reading the comments on the original question I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. I didn't see you want *random* strings in different languages... I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: well, it doesn't mean much. Maybe he wants to extract a random word out of a dictionary, choosing the dictionary depending on the language? either way, this question is going to get closed, and likely to be deleted. Meanwhile, people coming after looking for `string,different,language,javascript` will see your list of i18n projects :-)

Comment: @Andrew, it is a game where you need to guess word. For example: word 'apple' can be hiden in the string 'alrpepqyv'. As you can, see there are redundant chars in the string. But in another language there are other chars

Comment: @crumb you should specify that in your question, then it won't get closed. To solve that I think you're going to need to have two things: a wordlist to internationalize (translate) and a character list to sample. The tools listed can help with the translation part, and you could adapt that for character sampling as well.